# How can I put excel data to the dictionary?

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna put excel data to the dictionary.
Excel is
[image: excel]
views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd

book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel.xlsx')
sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)

large_item = None
data_dict = {}
for row_index in range(1,sheet3.nrows):
    rows3 = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    large_item = rows3[1] or large_item
    data_dict = rows3
```

Now when I printed out `print(data_dict)`,['', '4', '10', 'Karen', ''] was shown.Before,I wrote `data_dict.extend(rows3)` in place of `data_dict = rows3`,but in that time dict has not extend error happens.My ideal output is

```
data_dict = {
    1: {
        user_id: 1,
        name_id: 1,
        name: Blear,
        age: 40,
        man: false,
        employee: leader,
    },
    2: {
        user_id: 2,
        name_id: 5,
           ・
　　　　　　 ・
　　　　　　 ・
    },
           ・
　　　　　　 ・
　　　　　　 ・
}
```

How should I write to achieve my goal?

Comment: We can work around this problem and simplify it. Instead of parsing an excel, we can parse a csv. There are many libraries to support parsing a CSV so I would suggest we go that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is :

```
data_dict = rows3
```

This doesn't add rows3 to data_dict, this set is value. So data_dict is equal to the last row.

To add element to a dict you need to do this:

```
data_dict[KEY] = VALUE
```

Your key will be the row index.

Now, you want another dict like VALUE

```
{
    user_id: 1,
    name_id: 1,
    name: Blear,
    age: 40,
    man: false,
    employee: leader,
}
```

So for each row you need to construct this dict, use headers and cell value to do it.

I don't test this code, it's just to give you an idea to how to do it.

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd

book3 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel.xlsx')
sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)

headers = sheet3.row_values(0)
large_item = None
data_dict = {}
for row_index in range(1,sheet3.nrows):
    rows3 = sheet3.row_values(row_index)
    large_item = rows3[1] or large_item

    # Create dict with headers and row values
    row_data = {}
    for idx_col,value in enumerate(rows3):
        header_value = headers[idx_col]
        # Avoid to add empty column. A column in your example
        if header_value:
            row_data[headers[idx_col]] = value
     # Add row_data to your data_dict with 
     data_dict[row_index] = row_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's library `pandas` for an easy solution:

```
from pandas import *
xls = ExcelFile('your_excel_file.xls')
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
df.to_dict()
```